# Example of properties so that "any two properties imply the third"

Tags: logic, soft-question, education

I realise this is not a mathematics question per se, but it relates to *teaching* mathematics, and should have simple closed answers - therefore I have decided that MSE is an appropriate platform.

In mathematics, there are many examples of properties $\{P,Q,R\}$ so that any two imply the third. For example

- A Kähler manifold: $\{\text{Complex, Riemannian, Symplectic}\}$.
- $n$ is prime, $n$ is even, $n^n = n^2$.

My question is, are there any simple (non mathematics) examples of properties satisfying this rule? Like colours, or flavours.

One way to artificially create such a collection of three properties is to start with any two properties $\{P,Q\}$, and then define a third property $R$ to be "$P$ and $Q$". While it is certainly true that any two of $P,Q$, and $R$ will imply the third, $R$ alone will also imply the other two. The properties aren't "symmetric", and it isn't interesting. Therefore, we must add an extra condition: no property implies either of the remaining two properties.

**My Question:** Give three properties $\{P,Q,R\}$ (which are non-mathematical in nature) so that

1. Any two properties imply the third.
2. No single property implies any of the other two.

Thank you!

Comment: [relevant](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-out-of-three)

Comment: `non-mathematical in nature` Where is the line drawn? Would the following for example qualify as an answer: **P**  the lake is round, **Q** the lakeshore length is $2 \pi$ km, **R** the lake area is $\,\pi\,$ km$^2$.

Comment: I think this isn't an easy question to answer, if for no other reason than actual implication is difficult to pin down in a non-mathematical setting. The classic implication "If it is raining, I'll get wet" doesn't really work. What if you're inside or under cover? What if you have an umbrella? What if a machine with a thousand high-powered lasers evaporate every droplet before they can hit you? Real life has the potential to be messy and riddled with caveats, even if some of them are absurd!

Comment: Donald is the US President, Melania is the US First Lady, Donald and Melania are married.

Comment: If she buys kippers it will not rain, trout live in trees, I do not love her anymore. (I'm using the last opportunity to make a joke [before they ban it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/). If you don't know the sketch, you can Google it.)

Comment: @Rahul Not quite--although the First Lady is usually the president's wife, [she doesn't have to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Lady_of_the_United_States#Non-spouses_in_the_role).

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Damn it. [Theo was right!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862902/example-of-properties-so-that-any-two-properties-imply-the-third?noredirect=1#comment5906889_2862902)

Comment: How exact do they have to be?  The phrase "maternal uncle" means the brother or brother in law of my mother so:  "Bob is my maternal uncle"  "Alisha is my mother".  "Bob is my mother's brother or brother in law" ought to do it.  Of course if Theo's point is that is definition and not implication then ... I can't really argue but... well, does the OP *really* need such precise examples. Or we could do:  Sam and Ellen are my biological parents.  Grace is Sam and Ellen's biological daughter.  Grace is my full biological sister. Definition and implication gets pretty blurry in real life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One dollar is worth $\frac67$ euro.
2. One euro is worth $\frac78$ pounds.
3. One pound is worth $\frac43$ dollars.

Comment: (Assuming an exactly arbitrage-free market. Forex trading comes pretty close, though).

Comment: Ah nice this is literally: a = b, b = c, a = c. Very simple.

Answer (score 3):

(Not nonmathematical)

In an $n$-dimensional vector space consider the statements about a subset $S$:

- $S$ is independent.
- $S$ spans.
- $S$ has cardinality $n$.

Answer (score 2):

First, an example of three predicates such that any two imply the *negation* of the third:

In a house on the (straight) seashore, you can look out to the distance in three directions at $120°$ angles to each other. Then looking out to sea in two directions implies that you don't in the third.

Now a slightly more contrived example of three predicates such that any two imply the third:

You're trying to break out of a prison. You dug a tunnel, but apparently you miscalculated, and you've emerged in a watchtower. If it's one of the watchtowers on the corners of the prison, you could still escape by going back down and digging a bit further, but if it's the watchtower in the centre of the prison you should go back to your cell and cover your tracks or you'll be caught.

The watchtowers are round, and the outer watchtowers are centred on the corners of the rectangular prison, so that $90°$ of their circumference faces the prison and $270°$ faces the outside. You have time to make three tiny holes in the wall to get your bearings, so you decide to make them at $120°$ angles to get the best possible overview of the situation. But then after looking out onto the prison yard through two of them, you realize that any two such observations imply the third...

Comment: "Any two imply the negation of  the third" would be any three properties that are contradictory.